# Get Facebook Page / Profile URL

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently building an application which also allow users to specify their profile URLs for the various social network such as Facebook, Twitter, Google+ and etc. I will focus this question on Facebook instead for the start.

To allow users to easily input their profile links easily, I will like to have a button on their "Settings" page which they will login to their Facebook account, select the page or profile and it will automatically fill in the Textfield.

I'm new to FB and other social network APIs. It will be good if there is some samples or a documentation I can read up. I've spend sometime on the documentation but don't find anything that mention this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simple Graph API request gives you the user profile link.

```
/me?fields=link
```

Result:

```
{
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=XXXXX", 
  "id": "XXXXX"
}, 
{
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/first.last", 
  "id": "YYYYY"
}
```

Learn how to use the Graph API here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Quote from docs: `links: The user's posted links` – so not what’s being asked for here. `username` is the relevant field – because appending that to `www.facebook.com/` leads to the user’s profile. Nowadays every user should have a username set – if not by themselves, then it will be one automatically created by Facebook. Alternatively, using just the numeric user id and put it at the end of `www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=…` is also possible; FB will redirect automatically.

Comment: Wrong. `links` *does* give back the `profile.php?id=` URL even if the user didn't set his username.

Comment: Wrong. You mean `link`, not `links`. (Yes, the first one actually does what you said about the second one.)

Answer (score 0):

You should go through the below link it explains alot ,you can extract information from Facebook using Fql and get all the necessary info for registering user with your site.
I have also used it in my website [2shar.in](http://2shar.in)

[Facebook javascript api example](http://thinkdiff.net/facebook/graph-api-javascript-base-facebook-connect-tutorial/)